# Ably revoking a token individually and by group

Tags: ably-realtime

I'd like to be able to revoke my tokens in groups and also revoke them individually. Is there a way to assign multiple revocation keys so that either a string for the group or a string for the individual will match? Another solution for my particular case is if it's possible to target both channel and clientId for the same token so that I can use the group name for the `revocationKey` field.